# Remove empty lines or other editing features in Visual Studio

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio, text-editing

In order to use column mode in Notepad++, you press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> button and start dragging.
In order to use column mode in Visual Studio, you press the <kbd>ALT</kbd> button and start dragging.

To my humble opinion, this similarity is not a coincidence. So, I wonder, what about other editing features of Notepad++, like "Remove Empty lines", the feature I'm currently interested in? Is this feature also implemented in Visual Studio and in case yes, how can I call it?

Comment: Is your question just about 'Remove Empty Lines'? Because in that case the answer is a simple 'No' (the feature is not implemented in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my humble opinion, this similarity is not a coincidence.

It may not be. That is, it is entirely possible one development community looked at the features of one editor and decided they wanted those features in their own editor.

> So, I wonder, what about other editing features of Notepad++, like "Remove Empty lines", the feature I'm currently interested in? Is this feature also implemented in Visual Studio and in case yes, how can I call it?

To the best of my knowledge, this feature isn't implemented in the same way in Visual Studio. These are still separate development communities. One editor likely isn't simply copying the features of another wholesale.

You can get roughly the same result, however, by [searching and replacing with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453160/remove-empty-lines-in-text-using-visual-studio/52780071). Note that the linked Stack Overflow question [has an answer for Visual Studio 2017 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780071/3395469) that may allow you to manually create a shortcut to delete blank lines (but see the the comments).